# Spring JSP Binding a Map

Tags: java, jsp, binding, spring-mvc

I have a form in spring mvc 2.
My command class contains a complex map that I need to bind.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Class3>> class2Map;
```

In JSP I can iterate over command class and `<c:out>` map values of Class3 i.e. nameToGet & anyElement3.
But When I try to bind it with form

I am using

```
<c:forEach items="${class1.class2List}" var="item" varStatus="itemRow">
   <c:forEach var="map" items="${item.class2Map}" varStatus="mapRow">
      <c:forEach var="innerMap" items="${map.value}" varStatus="innerMapRow">
```

for iteration. I am binding like

```
<form:input path="class2List[${itemsRow.index}].class2Map[${mapRow.index}].value[0].anyElement3" />
```

it throws exception like

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'class1[0].class2Map[0].value[0].anyElement3' of bean class [Class1]: Bean property 'class1[0].class2Map[0].value[0].anyElement3' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

My Classes looks like

```
Class1 (Command Class)
List<Class2> class2List;
String anyElement1;

Class2
Map<String, Map<String, Class3>> class2Map;
String anyElement2;

Class3
Map<String, Class3> class3Map;
String nameToGet;
String anyElement3;
```

I am successfully binding other data members of command class. How can I bind this map to Spring Form?

Comment: Please fill in the dots; it may help getting better suggestions.

Comment: It contains something like this:: Invalid property 'commandClassName[0].mapName[0].value[0].anyElement3' of bean class [commandClassName]

Comment: Do you think the idea mentioned [here](http://blog.vergiss-blackjack.de/2010/04/iterating-over-nested-objects-in-a-spring-form/) could help?

Comment: Actually mine case is Map within Map. If I was only having Map<String, Class3> then it will work.

Comment: Can you also please add you complete loop? The index variables can be understood better.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure class1 has getters and setters for each field.

```
public Class1{
    String nameToGet;
    String anyElement3;

    public String getNameToGet(){
       return nameToGet;
    }

    public void setNameToGet(String nameToGet){
       this.nameToGet = nameToGet;
    }

    public String getAnyElement3(){
       return anyElement3;
    }

    public void setAnyElement3(String anyElement3){
       this.anyElement3 = anyElement3;
    }
}
```

There should also be similar getters and setters for:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Class1>> mapName;
```

Comment: I have all getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

In your form backing object, create the object(s) you wish to bind.

```
public class Class1Form{
     private String element3;
     //Other properties needed in your form.

     public String getElement3(){
          return element3;
     }

     public setElement3(String element){
          element3 = element;
     }
     //Other getters and setters.
}
```

Comment: Yes I created so. Suppose Class1Form is your command class. It will contains element3 as data member. It will also contain map(as defined by me) as data member. How to bind that map?

Answer (score 0):

Using the idea mentioned [here](http://blog.vergiss-blackjack.de/2010/04/iterating-over-nested-objects-in-a-spring-form/), can you try this:

```
class1[${itemRow.index}].class2Map['${mapRow.current.key}'].anyElement3
```

The idea is that inside the loop for `mapRow`, now it's iterating over a Map, so each `Map.Entry` should be available.

Comment: Two guesses. (1) In the second loop you have `var="map"`, you should be able to use `class1[${itemRow.index}].class2Map['${map.key}'].anyElement3` (2) Since the key types are all `String`, I believe a `'` was missing around the key.